# How can I tell if my perl process has used the regex $PREMATCH/$MATCH/$POSTMATCH vars (or the short equivilents $`/$'/$&)?

Tags: regex, perl

How can I tell if my perl process has used the regex vars `$PREMATCH`/`$MATCH`/`$POSTMATCH` (or the short equivilents `` $` ``/`$'`/`$&`)?

My perl webapp makes heavy use of [`Data::FormValidator::Results`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::FormValidator::Results), which, in some cases, uses `$PREMATCH`/`` $` `` inside an `eval()`.

I don't want to wade through all 200 invocations of the validator to check whether I trigger the codepath which uses `` $` ``, so is there anything I can inspect at runtime to see if any of the match vars have been used during the child process runtime?

I'd like to put a logging handler in at child process exit time which would `warn()` if one of the match vars has been used.

Comment: [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Performance-issues) mentions that "The Devel::NYTProf and Devel::FindAmpersand modules can help you find uses of these problematic match variables in your code." And FYI, the performance issues associated with them have been fixed as of 5.20.0, so you may not have to worry about it, depending on your setup.

Comment: Cheers! Issue was spotted by NYTProf. The webapps run on a mixture of v5.10.1 and 5.16.1, so they wil be affected by the match vars perf issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell if my perl process has used the regex vars `$PREMATCH/$MATCH/$POSTMATCH` (or the short equivalents `` $`/$'/$& ``)?

[perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Performance-issues) recommends using [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) and [Devel::FindAmpersand](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::FindAmpersand), but *Mastering Regular Expressions* claims that Devel::FindAmpersand is unreliable* and recommends [Devel::SawAmpersand](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::SawAmpersand) instead:

```
$ perl -MData::FormValidator -MDevel::SawAmpersand=sawampersand -e'warn if sawampersand'
Warning: something's wrong at -e line 1.
$ perl -MDevel::SawAmpersand=sawampersand -e'warn if sawampersand'
```

Alternatively, build perl with debugging symbols and run with `-Dr`:

```
$ perl -Dr -MData::FormValidator -e1
...
Enabling $` $& $' support.

EXECUTING...

$ perl -Dr -e1
Omitting $` $& $' support.

EXECUTING...
```

So, just `use`ing Data::FormValidator is enough to enable `$&` handling.

If you're running Perl 5.20.0+, the [performance issues associated with `$&` and friends have been fixed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Performance-issues). (A partial fix was also implemented in Perl 5.18.0.) If not, you're stuck with the performance hit, but I would recommend profiling your application to make sure regex processing is really causing an issue before making any changes.

---

* The author doesn't elaborate, but I found that Devel::FindAmpersand ignores the contents of `BEGIN` blocks:

```
$ perl -MDevel::FindAmpersand -e'$&'
Found evil variable $& in file -e, line 1
$ perl -MDevel::FindAmpersand -e'BEGIN { $& }'
```

Devel::SawAmpersand, on the other hand, doesn't:

```
$ perl -MDevel::SawAmpersand=sawampersand -e'$&; END { warn if sawampersand }'
Warning: something's wrong at -e line 1.
$ perl -MDevel::SawAmpersand=sawampersand -e'BEGIN { $& } END { warn if sawampersand }'
Warning: something's wrong at -e line 1.
```

Devel::FindAmpersand uses the B module to walk the optree and compare variable names against a regex, while Devel::SawAmpersand uses XS code to examine the `PL_sawampersand` variable directly, which I think explains the difference.

Comment: Very useful information but it might not clear up OP's question. I think the confusion is that OP thinks that the performance hit will be taken after the first *runtime use* of `$&` and friends, while in reality `PL_sawampersand` is set the first time code is *compiled* that mentions `$&` and friends, meaning as soon as FormValidator is loaded, regardless of whether those methods are called.

Comment: @hobbs Good point, I got carried away with the details. I'll try to clarify tomorrow. In the meantime, your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: I was unsure whether the performance hit would be turned on at runtime for Data::FormValidator::Result as the $& and $` I initially saw in the file were in a single-quoted string that was optionally later eval()ed. This (really clear and useful) answer showed that it was happening at compile time, so I looked again, and found another $& in regular code.

Comment: There is an open [RT case](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=68313) for this from 2011. For my purposes, where I'm not using FormValidator to untaint variables, I think I'll just coment out the single offending line in Results.pm

Comment: @hobbs "OP thinks that the performance hit will be taken after the first *runtime* use of `$&` and friends, while in reality `PL_sawampersand` is set the first time code is *compiled* that mentions `$&` and friends" I think the OP is right in the case of string `eval`: `perl -MDevel::SawAmpersand=sawampersand -e'BEGIN { sub foo { eval q{$&}; } } warn if sawampersand()'`. If `foo()` is never called, the `eval` never runs, so `PL_sawampersand` is never set.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot sure, in that case the code isn't compiled until the eval is hit. But it turns out that FormValidator has a non-eval-guarded `$&`.